# Rails Arel query, get columns a certain duration before now

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, psql, arel

I have a SQL query that I am trying to construct using Arel to try and check if a timestamp is a certain amount of time ago, something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE updated_at < NOW() - some_table.some_durations;
```

Specifically I'm unsure of how to insert the `NOW()` into the query in Arel or specify that a timestamp should be a certain duration in the past. This is as close as I can get, but is obviously wrong:

```
t = SomeTable.arel_table
t.project(Arel.star).where(t[:created_at].lt(t[:some_durations]))
```

Comment: `t.project(Arel.star).where(t[:created_at].lt(Arel.sql('NOW() - some_tables.some_durations')))` would this work?

Comment: This looks like it does what I need it to do! If you wanna post it as an answer I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```rb
t.project(Arel.star).where(t[:created_at].lt(Arel.sql('NOW() - some_tables.some_durations')))
```